# how to POP with animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am triggering a Navigator.pop event and I want to fade out the transition to the page.
I have tried Fluro but not I'm not interested in implementing it.

This what I'm doing :

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Cart"),
        leading: Hero(
          tag: "cartIcon",
          child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No one answered, But i found the solution ,you can do like this using MaterialPageRoute class

CLASS:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class CustomNavRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  CustomNavRoute({WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings})
      : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    if (settings.isInitialRoute) return child;

    return new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
  }
}
```

And Call the class like this :-

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(context,CustomNavRoute(builder: (context) => IntroScreen()));
```

Also on push

```
Navigator.push(context, CustomNavRoute(builder: (context) => LoginSignup()));
```

This will apply fadein transition on PUSH and POP to page !

Comment: this is not pop! Imagine I came for IntroPage to login Page. I will be again push intro page over intro page

Comment: Please check if it is showing animation on pop also.

Comment: settings.isInitialRoute > settings.name=='/'

Answer (score 6):

the pop method use the same Route used in push method, so you can put the required animation in the push method, just make sure you add `reverseTransitionDuration` to the route to make its animation more noticeable.

```
//push to page2
Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(
    transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    reverseTransitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      final tween = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0);
      final fadeAnimation = animation.drive(tween);
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: fadeAnimation,
        child: child,
      );
    },
  ),
);


//pop from page2
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use different animation when push and pop, you can do it like this in CustomPageRouteBuilder

```
  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    final PageTransitionsTheme theme = Theme.of(context).pageTransitionsTheme;
    Animation<double> onlyForwardAnimation;
    switch (animation.status) {
      case AnimationStatus.reverse:
      case AnimationStatus.dismissed:
        onlyForwardAnimation = kAlwaysCompleteAnimation;
        break;
      case AnimationStatus.forward:
      case AnimationStatus.completed:
        onlyForwardAnimation = animation;
        break;
    }
    return theme.buildTransitions<T>(this, context, onlyForwardAnimation, secondaryAnimation, child);
  }
```

check [flutter issue 25338](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25338) and [github](https://gist.github.com/HansMuller/dbcbec1962dd8d810279bad2f1fd8c3b)