# In Flutter Transition back animation

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, navigation, widget

I am trying to make **Page Transition Animation** in flutter like the one in the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7CAMPdUu8o , Its work but I want the animation to happen only
when the screen pop I mean when I use `Navigator.of(context).pop();`.
**I appreciate your help**

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PageRouteBuilder`. Below example will helpful to you.

[PageRouteTransition](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation)

Or you should go with below question too.

[POP with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342299/how-to-pop-with-animation-in-flutter)